# How to recognise an ajax application?

Tags: ajax

How can I decide if a website is using Ajax technology? What are the characteristics that I should I look in the website to tell it is an ajax application?

Comment: That's not really a programming question... Why would you want to know?

Comment: Search the JS source files for `xhr` or `$.ajax`, `$.post` etc.

Comment: You might want to read this as a starting point: [Wiki: Ajax (programming)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming))

Comment: @Rudie: Why would you *not* want to know? ;)

Comment: Try loading the page up and then going offline. See if you get any errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can just look into the javascript source code and search for `.ajax`, `.post` and `.get` . If you find any of these they use ajax technologies.

You can also look at the network requests a page sends, if the page sends requests after loading the full page without you seeing it refreshing it probably uses ajax.

Comment: Maybe they included jQuery, but don't use it. Maybe they're using ajax without jQuery.

Comment: Good point @Rudie. You have to put it into context of course. But manually reviewing the sourcecode would give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Search the javascript for `XMLHttpRequest`. Beyond that, the working definition of Ajax is rather too broad to look for, say, specific behaviours.

Comment: Every library includes `XMLHttpRequest`. Doesn't mean it's used.

Comment: Depends how you define Ajax. As I understand it, the "asynchronous" part pretty much demands the use of `XMLHttpRequest`. If the code isn't actually *using* it, it isn't really doing Ajax, but that's an argument for a different venue.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing special about websites using AJAX, it just means they make an asynchronous call to the server at some point. You can't know for certain that the website will make such a call unless you run it.